# Adding multiple categorical labels to a bar chart in R

Tags: r, graphics

Say I have some data on some experiment I conducted on Earth and on Wayne's World. There are control and treatment means:

```
means1<-c(1,2)
means2<-c(1.5,2.5)
data<-cbind(means1,means2)
rownames(data)=c('ctrl','treatment')
colnames(data)=c('Earth','Waynes World')
```

I would like to plot this data, so I do.

```
barplot(data,beside=T)
```

This generates paired control and treatment bars, separated by planet. Each pair of bars has an x axis label specifying what planet they are from. What I would like is a second set of x-axis labels underneath each bar that specifies ctrl or treatment. Bonus if you tilt this second set of labels, they don't overlap the first labels, and everything looks pretty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think something like this describes what you're after

```
bp<-barplot(data,beside=T, xaxt="n") 
mtext(text=rownames(data)[row(bp)], at=bp, line=1, side=1)
mtext(text=colnames(data), at=colMeans(bp), line=2.2, side=1)
```

[image]